# How to retrieve data from flask using Ajax without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, flask

In my html, I want to submit a form to server-side.
However, after the server-side(flask）receives this data,
I want the html page retrieve the data, and display it by Ajax without JQuery

I spent all day on that please help me. here is my data:

```
  <div class="login-container">
    <form action="/" method="POST" name='form1'>
      <table class="form-table">
          <tr>
            <td><span class="title-name">name:<span id="start">*</span>:&nbsp;</span>
              <input id="name" type="text" name="name" required></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>
              <button class="button" type="reset" name="clear" for="form1">Clear</button>
              <button class="button" type="submit" name="submit" for="form1" onclick="submitForm()">Search</button>
            </td>               
          </tr>  
  </form>
  </div>
  </div>
```

my js:

```
function submitForm(){
    //checkInput(); 
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        console.log(this.status);
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("bottom").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
      }
    };
    xhttp.open("POST", "/res", true);
    xhttp.send();   
}
```

my flask

```
from flask import Flask,send_file
from flask import request,jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)
req_dict=None
req_json=None

@app.route('/',methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
    return send_file('index.html')



@app.route('/res',methods=['GET','POST'])
def success():
    if(request.method=='POST'):
        req_dict=dict(request.form)
        req_json=jsonify(req_dict)

    return req_json
```

the data flow is : front-end > server side > ajax > front-end.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent an event, like `submit`, to use its default behavior, use: [`Event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault). This allows you to create your own behavior on when something has to happen when a form is submitted.

Also, instead of listening for a `click` on the submit button, listen for `submit` on the form element. That is the element that you want to control.

Try to use `addEventListener` instead of inline attributes to listen for events. It will make your code a lot cleaner and easier to maintain and using inline attributes such as `onclick` is considered an outdated practice.

```
<form id="form-one" action="/" method="POST" name='form1'>
  <table class="form-table">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label for="name" class="title-name">name:<span id="start">*</span>:&nbsp;</label>
        <input id="name" type="text" name="name" required></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button class="button" type="reset" name="clear" for="form1">Clear</button>
        <button class="button" type="submit" name="submit" for="form1">Search</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

I noticed a typo in the `xhttp` variable in side the`onreadystatechange` callback. Instead of `xhttp`, you used `xmlhttp`. Correct it.

```
var formOne = document.getElementById('form-one');

function submitForm(event){
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default submit behavior.
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        console.log(this.status);
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("bottom").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
      }
    };
    xhttp.open("POST", "/res", true);
    xhttp.send();   
}

formOne.addEventListener('submit', submitForm);
```